# onClick() - newRequestQueue(this) and getApplicationContext() error?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I'm trying to do a newRequestQueue using Volley and get SharedPreferences:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
...
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
...

 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

...
            -> SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref01", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String username = pref.getString("username", "No name defined");

LRequest lRequest = new lRequest(pid, username);
            -> RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(lRequest);

...

}

    }
}
```

The problem is that it is inside the `onClick()` event and it gives me this errors:

```
cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()
```

and

```
Volley cannot be apply to com.st.mf.CardAdapter.ViewHolder
```

how can I solve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, `getApplicationContext()` is not a method of any Adapter class. You need a Context to get the `SharedPreferences`, yes.

Similarly for  `Volley.newRequestQueue(this)`; where the `this` usage there  needs to be a `Context`, not an Adapter.

---

Realistically, you call Volley from the Activity and then fill the adapter with your data from there.

Otherwise, if you really wanted a `Context`, your constuctor needs one.

```
public class CardAdapter extends ...
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, ...) {
        this.context = context;
        ...
    }

    ...

    context.getSharedPreferences("pref01", MODE_PRIVATE);

    ...

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

And then when you create the adapter...

```
CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ...);
```